# Dictation button outside the keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ipad

Is there a way to perform dictation on click of a button outside the iOS keyboard. 
For ex: I have a `UITextField` with microphone button right. On the click of this button, it should open the same dialog/view as when microphone button is clicked inside the keyboard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have been doing a research on this for a while now and could not find a solution for this yet.

**You cannot trigger the microphone** button outside the keyboard as in the native iPhone search bar in the home screen. This is a private API which is **not available for development**.

The best possible alternative is to use the [Speech](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech) framework provided by Apple available in iOS 10.0+ and build your own custom UI to convert speech to text.

Hope this information helps! :)

Answer (score -4):

UITextField conforms to UITextInput Protocol ( under the section Using Dictation are methods of interest). In this protocol is a method dictationRecordingDidEnd that you can override.

One way is to subclass UITextField and implement the above mentioned method and any others of interest from the UITextInput protocol.

example subclass .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TextField : UITextField

@end
```

.m

```
#import "TextField.h"

@implementation TextField

-(void)dictationRecordingDidEnd {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}// done is pressed by user after dictation

@end
```

Comment: the OP asked wheter the microphone button action can be triggered outside the keyboard. This answer is not relevant to the question. You are talking about getting a callback after dictation is completed.